# How to pass value of spinner in doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I want to pass value from spinner to doInBackground in AsyncTask. I use this code:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(0);

    OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Integer item = (Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);

public void onClick(View view) {
    SomeTask = new SomeTask();
    SomeTask.execute();

class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground (Void...params){

        //do something with variable item
        }
    }

   //do all next things
```

And I don't know how to pass variable item to doInBackground. Help me please and thank you.

Comment: use Integer item as a global variable, assign it in onItemSelected and you can access it anywhere within the class.

Comment: I know a library which  does asynchronous easily and it can help you to populate a spinner if you are interested i will share it.

Comment: What are you trying to pass?

Comment: Oh i did item global and it starts working. It was so simple... :) Thank you very match!